# Update a table with multiple columns matching a pattern

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I would like to write down a query like this in MySQL.

```
update mytable set x = 3*x where x is like '%something%' and row = 34
```

Updating a multiple columns have specific pattern.
I was wondering how to do this. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: `SET x = 3*x` makes me think `x` is a numeric value, but `x LIKE '%something%'` makes me think `x` is character data. Which is it?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `row = 34`.

Comment: hi! x should be a column of the table

Comment: row should be another columnname

Comment: what i essentially need to do is to write an update statement where the updated columns are specified by "like"

Comment: Are you trying to rename the field (column name) ?

Comment: @Alex It is obvious that `x` is a column of the table. What is confusing is that you are treating that column as both a numeric value (`SET x = 3*x`) and as a string (`x LIKE '%something%'`).

Comment: @HashSu: no, I am trying to update already existing columns that take on numeric values

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: I understand that the syntax is incorrect but I dont see another way of writing it down.

Comment: @HashSu: what I would like is the update statement to update multiple fields based on lexical similarities

Comment: @Alex What is your exepected result after the update...?

Comment: @HashSu: all the columns in the table that are named like 'x' to be multiplied by 3

Comment: really ?  all the column names are named as 'xxxx' ?

Comment: I meant to say "something"... all the columns that contain the word "something" in them

Comment: You can't do a multi  update on the column name having a specific pattern, try doing through a script. I can tell you the logic

Comment: please do, it would be extremely helpful

Comment: god I know - cant really figure out how to do this in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do a multi update on the column name having a specific pattern, try doing through a script.

Comment: np let me know if any thing i can do

Comment: Perl? Not much of a Perl community out there. I migrated to PHP a decade ago. Using unpopular languages can hurt collaboration on coding teams if nobody can cover for you.